# UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() Retina resolution?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm taking a picture of my screen and manipulating it by using `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()`.  Everything is working just fine.  However, on an iPhone 4, the resolution looks pretty shabby as it seems like the image it uses is standard resolution, not @2x.  Is there any way to increase the resolution of the resulting image?

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You should use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` which allows you to set the scale factor.  Use a scale factor of 0.0f to use the device's scale factor.

Comment: For anyone who sees this in the future, this is for iOS 4+ only.