# UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext returns low resolution Image

Tags: xcode, uiimage, uigraphicscontext

I have two high resolution image that i've been merging using UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext drawInRect. But the method returns a low resolution image. please help. Heres my code.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(phoneSize.width, phoneSize.height));
  for(int x=0;x<arr_UIImages.count;x++){
    NSValue *point = [app.arr_boxPositions objectAtIndex:x];
    NSValue *size = [arr_cropSizes objectAtIndex:x];
    CGPoint p = point.CGPointValue;
    CGSize s = size.CGSizeValue;
    s.width = s.width * phoneSize.width;
    s.height = s.height *phoneSize.height;
    p.x = p.x * .01;
    p.y = p.y * .01;

    p.x = p.x *phoneSize.width;
    p.y = p.y *phoneSize.height;

    float xPos = p.x - (s.width/2);
    float yPos = p.y - (s.height/2);
    UIImage *temp = [arr_UIImages objectAtIndex:x];
    [temp drawInRect:CGRectMake(xPos*2,yPos*2,temp.size.width, temp.size.height)];
  }

  UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(finalImage , nil, nil, nil);
```

The width and size of my image is correct but the image have a low dpi. Please help. thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4965155/1489885) answer?

Comment: Yup I tried this one,  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(phoneSize.width, phoneSize.height), NO, 0.0); But nothing's change.